# Angular2: check empty form if radio button is set

Tags: javascript, forms, angular

I have an Angular2 child component that consist in a radio button and an input text area:

```
<div class="form-group" *ngIf="message" >
  <input type="text" class="form-control"
  required [(ngModel)]="message.message"
  name="message"/>

  <input type="radio" class="form-control"
   [checked] = "message.default == 1"
   [value] = "message.default"
   (change)="onSelectionChange(message)"
  name="default" >{{message.language}}<br>
</div>
```

Parent component show than one child component (dinamycally) inside a form with a submit button. 
Now when i click submit button, if one of child's text area is empty an error message is showed, but i would that message is showed only if the radio button is checked.
How can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could add 1 more condition like this

```
<div *ngIf="!message.message && message.default == 1">
  Error here...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used `[(ngModel)]` for text box, you can also use `[(ngModel)]` for radio button also

```
<input type="radio" class="form-control"
   [checked] = "message.default.value == 1"
   [value] = "message.default.value"
   (change)="onSelectionChange(message)"
   name="default"
   [(ngModel)]="message.default" >
```

Then you can check the value